# How to make this conditional column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

datasz is the name of my initial dataframe. This dataframe contains a column called 'CELL' with cells sequences. normal_cells is another dataframe that contains only the normal cell sequences from datasz under a column named 'CELL'. I am trying to add a conditional column (is_normal) into the datasz dataframe that basically asks itself if datasz['CELL'] is in normal_cells['CELL'] and returns 'normal' in the new column (is_normal) or returns 'tumor' in the column if it is not in the normal_cells['CELL'].
Here is my following code:

```
datasz =  pd.read_csv(...)    #Blurring out the read for privacy?
# datasz['CELL'] is the column with the cell sequences
normal_cells = pd.read_csv(...)  #Blurring out the read for privacy?
#normal_cells['CELL'] is the column with the cell sequences
```

What I am looking for is something like this

```
datasz['is_normal'] = [{AAACCTGGTGCTGTAT: normal
                       AAACGGGCATGTATGC:  tumor}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing the entire string in the 'CELL' column, then you can mark the normal cells with a column 'normal' in normal_cells, then use that column as a flag to test after merging both dataframes together.  Set the tumor value based on the test:

```
datasz = pd.DataFrame({'CELL': ["CATG", "AATG", "GGGG"]})
normal_cells = pd.DataFrame({'CELL': ["CATG", "AATG"]})
normal_cells['normal'] = 'normal'

datasz = datasz.merge(normal_cells, on='CELL', how='left')

datasz.loc[datasz['normal'] != 'normal', 'tumor'] = 'tumor'
datasz = datasz.fillna('')
```

to get

```
   CELL  normal  tumor
0  CATG  normal       
1  AATG  normal       
2  GGGG          tumor
```